# jQuery remove then add again for live search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a set of dynamically created content "boxes," generated by a wordpress plugin. Each box is contained within a div with class "front-page-post". I'm trying to create a "live search" that will remove non-matching boxes, but will also add them back when a user changes or erases their search term.

Using $(this).fadeOut(); and $(this).fadeIn(); works, but because the boxes aren't actually being removed - just hidden - the page layout doesn't dynamically update and the boxes stay where they were originally. I can get the page layout to update if I completely remove the boxes using $(this).remove(); but can't figure out how to re-add them back if the search term is updated.  Trying to store them within a hidden div on the page with class "store" but this isn't working either.

The page I'm working on is [here](http://www.safetysmart.com/wip).  Here is my code; any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#filter").keyup(function(){

    // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
    var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
    // Loop through the comment list
    $(".front-page-post").each(function(){

        // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) { 

            $(this).clone().appendTo("div.store");
            $(this).remove().delay(500); $(window).resize();
        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1

        } else {

          $(this).prepend( function() { $("div.store").contents(); } );

            count++;
        }
    });

    // Update the count
    var numberItems = count;
    $("#filter-count").text("Number of Resources = "+count);
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to figure it out, but this seems to work nicely on my browser.

the first line simply disables your function so i could try it in console, you dont need it.

[working pastebin sample](http://pastebin.com/LGdd4Tik)

Comment: Amazing, thank you!!  Only one small thing; after you enter a search term it seems to duplicate all of the boxes.  I updated my web page with your code so you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the site has positioned the blocks using positin:absolute, and top, left , which means you have to recalculate those, even if you remove the boxes.

Comment: I believe the plugin generating these boxes recalculates position on window resize, which is why I added the $(window).resize(); If you type in "tes" in the search box on the webpage you'll see this working.